# Why is Unity3D RaycastHit.textureCoord always 0,0?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
var startPoint = 
  shaft.transform.position 
  + shaft.transform.forward;
var ray = new Ray(
    startPoint, 
    -shaft.transform.forward
  );

RaycastHit rayCastHit;
Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayCastHit);
var textured2D = (Texture2D)discoBall.renderer.material.mainTexture;
Vector2 textureCoord = rayCastHit.textureCoord;
Debug.Log(string.Format(
    "{0},{1} at distance {2}", 
    textureCoord.x * textured2D.width, 
    textureCoord.y * textured2D.height, 
    rayCastHit.distance
  ));
```

I have a sphere with an object "Shaft" object inside it.  I work out a startPoint as a distance away from the shaft in the direction the shaft points (to get outside the sphere).  I then create a ray pointing back at the sphere with the same distance, so that it collides with the outside of my sphere.

The Debug.Log outputs x,y = 0,0 for the textureCoord, and the correct value of 0.35 for the distance.  Why is the textureCoord always 0,0 when I do in fact have a material with a texture on my sphere?

[image: Sphere properties]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually let me move my comment here, does the sphere use a mesh collider or a sphere collider? If it doesn't use a mesh collider, [textureCoord returns Vector2.zero](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html).

**Update**:

To change the collider type of a GameObject highlight it in the Unity editor and go to **Component->Physics->MeshCollider**.  If prompted to 'Replace Existing Component', select 'Replace'.

GameObjects added from Unity's **GameObject->Create_Other** menu tend to default to colliders based on the shape of the object (spheres, boxes, etc), since mesh colliders are computationally more expensive.

Comment: @PeterMorris Yes, it has a sphere **collider**.  Try switching to a mesh **collider**.  Component->Physics->MeshCollider, 'Yes' to replace.

Comment: If you add this to the answer, and also mention that the material type needs to be changed to "Advanced" so that "Read/Write enabled" can be checked then I will gladly accept it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PeterMorris Glad it helped.  One thing though, the part about changing the material to 'Read/Write' enabled is not accurate.  At least not in my test, my texture has 'Read/Write' disabled and still returns valid texture coordinates.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The Read/Write part was a problem I experoenced trying to read the pixel. Answer accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the texture2d width and height actually what you expect? Possibly maintexture is not the correct texture on the shader you are using.

Comment: Yes, 512x512 and the only texture I have on the material